# How to get 3 latest videos from youtube channel?

Tags: php, curl, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I know there are too many similar question like in my title, but I have problem that prevents me to make it works.

I tested with three accounts and all of them in one day exceeded "request quota". I can't even understand that how it was happen?

I'm using this code to get 3 latest videos from youtube channel:

```
$videoList = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId='.$channelID.'&maxResults='.$maxResults.'&key='.$API_key.''));  

foreach($videoList->items as $item){
          //Embed video
          if(isset($item->id->videoId)){
              echo '<div class="video">
                        <iframe width="100%" class="youtube-video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$item->id->videoId.'"  frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>';
          }
      }
```

Script works for some hour and after that result of code disappears and I get message that tell me I reached quota.

I created 3 new accounts, created only Youtube API v3 service for a project, but I can't even use it at all!

How to make this Youtube API V3 to work without any troubles to keep the script running?

Comment: try use this plugin it is working good with me

https://codecanyon.net/item/yt-channel-youtube-channel-and-video-details-api-v3-php-class/13746153

Comment: Is that code running every time the page loads? Cache the results instead to save on quota costs.

Comment: @johnh10, could you tell me how to cache it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems easy to parse it from the html video list, the xpath `//li/ul/li[contains(@class,'channels-content-item')]` gets you the list of videos, with a video li context node, the xpath `.//*[contains(@class,'yt-lockup-title')]/a` gets you the title and `.//*[@data-context-item-id]` gets you the node holding the id in the "data-context-item-id" attribute, putting it all together we get:

```
<?php    
declare(strict_types=1);
// $html = file_get_contents("html.html");
$html = file_get_contents("https://www.youtube.com/user/Tobuscus/videos?view=0&sort=dd&flow=grid");
$domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXPath($domd);
$videoList = $xp->query("//li/ul/li[contains(@class,'channels-content-item')]");
$parsed = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; ++$i) {
    $video = $videoList[$i];
    $title = trim($xp->query(".//*[contains(@class,'yt-lockup-title')]/a", $video)->item(0)->textContent);
    $id = $xp->query(".//*[@data-context-item-id]", $video)->item(0)->getAttribute("data-context-item-id");
    $parsed[$id] = $title;
}
var_dump($parsed);
```

which outputs:

```
array(3) {
  ["HKlOgarmkcY"]=>
  string(44) "I haven't Played this Game in a LONG Time..."
  ["YZac_eyIa0c"]=>
  string(37) "Something is happening in two days..."
  ["5gY_v-T9kAM"]=>
  string(14) "Dear Algorithm"
}
```

gotdammit im bored.

Comment: Hi! Im trying your code in wordpress, but i get an error with `declare(strict_types=1);` so if i delete it, i have no output for `var_dump`.

Comment: @Jose the strict_types part is not needed, and im not sure it's even compatible with wordpress; but if you have no var_dump output, it suggest you are getting an exception, check your php error logs, it's probably an error there explaining why you get no output